# How to pass parameters in C# GDI+ Windows Desktop

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm interested in learning about C# GDI+ and have googled many tutorials. I'm attempting to create a simple windows form that has two textbox controls and a button. I simply want to put a length dimension in one textbox and a height dimension in the other, click the button and have the app draw the rectangle on the window using those two entered dimensions. To date, all I have been able to do is locate tutorials where the rectangle parameters are hardcoded into the Form_Load and Form_Paint. How would I take the user input from the textboxes and pass them to make the app refresh and draw the rectangles on the button click?
Please let me know if more info is needed.
Thanks in advance for your knowledge!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap drwBitmap;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphicObj;
        drwBitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height,
           System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        graphicObj = Graphics.FromImage(drwBitmap);
        graphicObj.Clear(Color.White);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
        Rectangle rectObj;
        rectObj = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 200);
        graphicObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, rectObj);
        graphicObj.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, Graphics graphicsObj)
    {
        Graphics graphicsObj1 = graphicsObj;
        graphicsObj1.DrawImage(drwBitmap, 0, 0, drwBitmap.Width, drwBitmap.Height);
        graphicsObj.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: A) There is no point to drawing/painting anything in the FormLoad event because it hasnt been shown yet so Windows B) Where did you get that signature for the Paint event? Windows will pass you a *valid* graphics object as part of `PaintEventArgs` use that one. C) You should also look into the `using` block statements....for starters

Answer (score 1):

The current approach is quite strange as it draws directly to the form. It's difficult to modify as a bitmap is created early on and then must somehow be changed. Furthermore, there is no need for a bitmap.

A better approach is to create a custom control:

```
public class EllipseControl : Control
{
    private float m_ellipseWidth = 200;
    private float m_ellipseHeight = 120;

    public float EllipseWidth
    {
        get { return m_ellipseWidth; }
        set
        {
            m_ellipseWidth = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public float EllipseHeight
    {
        get { return m_ellipseHeight; }
        set
        {
            m_ellipseHeight = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var graphics = e.Graphics;
        using Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, 0, 0, EllipseWidth, EllipseHeight);
    }
}
```

This control can then be placed on the form. It has two properties: *EllipseWidth* and *EllipseHeight*.

In the event handler for the button click, you can take the values from the text fields and set them on the ellipse control.